# How to use free space on USB flash drive after 'dd' of debian installer?

Tags: debian, iso

I have an 32GiB USB flash drive.

I wrote Debian Live image to USB flash drive by "dd".

Now on USB flash drive 27 GiB free space.

I want to use this free space.

Comment: You have not been clear about the situation, so I can not tell you exactly. However try gparted. It should help. It can re-size and add partitions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create another partition on free space of USB after 'dd' installing debian](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/618615/create-another-partition-on-free-space-of-usb-after-dd-installing-debian)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a partitioning tool like [gparted](https://gparted.org/), available on the excellent [SystemRescueCd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/), to access your USB flash drive. Assuming your Debian installation is on the only partition on the flash drive (/dev/sdb1 or something similar - use lsblk and/or fdisk -l to check), you can use gparted to shrink the partition and create a second partition (or a number of them) in the 27GB of free space.
[image: Using lsblk and fdisk -l to find flash drive info]

Comment: Welcome, could you explain how to use Gparted to make the USB usable again (important steps). The same for `fdisk`.

Comment: Using Gparted with a USB drive is explained in detail elsewhere. I'm entirely too unambitious to repeat the steps here. :-)    But here is the link to one such page:   [link]https://www.howtogeek.com/howt17001o//how-to-format-a-usb-drive-in-ubuntu-using-gparted/  __Edited for clarity__