# Create another partition on free space of USB after 'dd' installing debian

Tags: debian, partition, live-usb

Basically a duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491116/how-to-use-free-space-on-usb-flash-drive-after-dd-of-debian-installer) question but being more clear and providing more details.

What I want is to have a USB drive with two things: The debian installer, and another partition using the remaining space of the USB. It should **not** be used for persistance within debian. Just a regular usable partition.

In my linked question fdisk/gparted is recommended, but those don't really work.

GParted shows this:
[image: gparted]

`lsblk`:

```
sdc              8:32   1   7.5G  0 disk  
├─sdc1           8:33   1   2.7G  0 part  
└─sdc2           8:34   1   2.9M  0 part
```

`fdisk /dev/sdc`:

> The device contains 'iso9660' signature and it will be removed by a
> write command. See fdisk(8) man page and --wipe option for more
> details.

I tried ignoring this and creating a third partition anyway, it worked but made debian unable to boot. The bootmenu shows up but when trying to boot it gives several errors about not finding an ext3/ext4 partition or something similar. My PC (nautilus file manager) also doesn't detect the debian partition anymore after the `fdisk` write with the third partition.

`fdisk -l`:

```
Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *        0 5706399 5706400  2.7G  0 Empty
/dev/sdc2        1600    7487    5888  2.9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

`dd` command used:
`dd if=debian.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=1M status=progress`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ISO hybrid images are crazy combinations of iso9660 format and multiple partition tables to make sure it boots everywhere. This is how the superblock looks:

```
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE    UUID                   LABEL
sdb    0x8001 iso9660 2020-09-26-10-19-19-00 Debian 10.6.0 amd64 n
sdb    0x1fe  dos                            
sdb    0x200  gpt                            
sdb    0x0    mac
```

You can't remove any of these. If you want to add a new partition, simply tell `fdisk` to not wipe other signatures on the device and use only the *dos* partition table using

```
fdisk --wipe=never -t dos /dev/sdX
```

and add a new partition. I did a quick test with Debian netinstall ISO and the new partition is usable and the installer still boots.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try tomorrow and report back. :)

Comment: Works perfectly! :)

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thanks @vojtech-trefny. I was trying to install Debian on an arm64 board. I had created a usb disk with the netinstall iso and was looking for a way to create an extra partition to store device tree files for my arm64 board.

Comment: Thanks. What commands do you use to create the other partition?

Answer (score 0):

The `fdisk --wipe=never` seems to be deprecated now.  I'm trying in Debian 11 and it no longer honours the request to not wipe.  Debian 10 works just fine (yes, the documentation still shows wipe can be always/never/auto, but it doesn't seem to actually still work.)

Just me, or has anybody else found this?

```
root@vostro:~# fdisk --wipe=never -t dos /dev/sdc

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.36.1).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

The device contains 'iso9660' signature and it may remain on the device. It is recommended to wipe the device with wipefs(8) or fdisk --wipe, in order to avoid possible collisions.

Command (m for help):
```

Comment: I used it on Debian11 and it seems to work fine, I think it just gives a warning, and the warning is different if you pass that argument or not. Also it's documented in the man page so I don't think it's deprecated